# Correcting for multiple hypothesis when using discrete choice models

Tags: multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, multinomial-logit, choice-modeling

I was wondering if anyone knew if there was any guidance regarding correcting for multiple hypothesis (using for example Bonferroni correction) when using discrete choice models (for example MNL or MXL models)? I've never seen this done in the literature, but wondering what the reasoning would be for not doing it...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.